# Async Report File Generation With Ping For File Completion

Tags: javascript, vb.net, asynchronous, async-await, long-polling

Recently, I have had need of designing an improved reporting system for generation of large reports.

The issue with the old system was how long the browser would hang on the request waiting for the file to be ready. If it took too long, the request would be timed out.

To avoid this, and make for a better UI, I have designed the following process:

- User clicks button.
- An ajax request is fired and awaited for the file name.
- An ajax request is fired and not awaited to generate the report (The test case for this is a WebMethod who's Thread sleeps for 5 seconds).
- An ajax ping based off of long polling will ping the server every x number of seconds to check if the file exists.

I was a bit rusty with Async, so a lot of my work was following by example. However, the final result I thought should work generated the following result:

> 9:23:51 AM
> 9:23:51 AM
> before ping
> ping 9:23:51 AM
> Your file is not ready for download...
> null
> ping 9:23:56 AM
> Your file is not ready for download...
> ping 9:23:57 AM
> Your file is not ready for download...
> ping 9:23:58 AM
> Your file is not ready for download...

The file creation would go off async and generate the file. But as soon as something else was awaited (the ping), the entire process would hang until the file was created, and then the ping logic would loop as desired.

My first attempt at a solution was not awaiting the ping either. However, I would be left with a promise I could not read to get the response of the ping out of.

The final solution I realized after a nights sleep was the ping call must be calling the same thread currently locked by the file creation. So I wrapped the whole file creation logic in a Task which achieved the result I desired.

However, whilst I have a solution, I still would like to understand the problem more.

Thank you for reading.

Code:

```
document.getElementById("btnGo").onclick = async function (e) {
    await LaunchReport(btn.attributes["bespokeReport"].value);
};

async function LaunchReport(report) {
    let fileName = await AjaxRequest("GenerateFileName", { report: report });
    let reportData;

    switch (report) {
        case "StandardReport": {
            console.log(new Date().toLocaleTimeString("en-US"));
            AjaxRequest("RunStandardReport", { fileName: fileName }).then(console.log);
            console.log(new Date().toLocaleTimeString("en-US"));

            break;
        }

        default: {
            //error logic
        }
    }
    console.log("before ping");
    await PingReport(fileName);
    console.log("after ping");
}

async function PingReport(fileName) {
    let response = await AjaxRequest("PingReportStatus", { fileName: fileName });
    console.log("ping " + new Date().toLocaleTimeString("en-US"));
    console.log(response);

    if (response != "ready") {
        await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 1000));
        await PingBespokeReport(fileName);
    } else {
        window.alert(response);
    }
}

async function AjaxRequest(action, data = null) {
    let r;

    await $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        data: JSON.stringify(data),
        dataType: "json",
        url: "/admin/reports.aspx/" + action,
        async: true,
        success: function (res) { r = res.d; },
        error: function (res) {
            console.log(res);
            r = res.d;
        }
    });

    return r;
}
```

The site is a .NET Framework 4.6.1 site.

```
<WebMethod>
Public Shared Sub RunStandardReport(fileName As String)
    Thread.Sleep(5000)
    ''Generate File Logic
End Sub

<WebMethod>
Public Shared Function PingReportStatus(fileName As String) As String
    Try
        Dim fileReady As Boolean = File.Exists("FileDirectory..." & "\" & fileName)

        If fileReady Then
            Return "ready"
        Else
            Return "Your file is not ready for download..."
        End If

    Catch ex As Exception
        Return "There was a problem looking for your file with the name: " & fileName
    End Try
End Function
```

Comment: in the line `await LaunchBespokeReport(btn.attributes["bespokeReport"].value);` ... what is `btn`

Comment: I don't understand why all this is necessary. An asynchronous request does not "hang" the browser. I don't see the additional value of a ping that says "ready". Then what? You still need the report, which presumably will still be delivered asynchronously from the very first request.

Comment: @JaromandaX btn is a button element on the page who holds what type of report is to be run in its attributes. It isn't clean and tidy but the page in question is also old and eventually going to be completely upgraded.

Comment: @trincot The file isn't delivered at the end of the request. The ping only says when it exists. The ping then stops and a button is made available who's onclick event delivers the file. The browser itself wasn't hanging. The ping logic which should have been fired every second, only started doing so after the RunStandardBespokeExcelReport delivered a response.

Comment: You used the word "hang" twice in your question. Now you say the browser isn't hanging. I am lost. I hope someone understands what you are writing, but this should be simple: a request to the server should be made to create the report, the response should be the report. The client uses a promise to await the report. The browser doesn't hang. You can even have your JavaScript play an animation or so.